# Does an onboard video affect the X windows configuration?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, dualhead

Does the onboard video on the motherboard affect the X windows configuration?

My system has onboard and pcie video.  The onboard video is a NVIDIA GeForce 7025 GPU, On Board Graphic Max. Memory Share Up to 512MB(Under OS By Turbo Cache). I have a pcie dual head video card installed with two monitors. The video card is a GeForce 8400 GS, with 512mb memory.

When installing Ubuntu 12.04, only one monitor worked.  When pulling up system settings- Displays it shows a laptop.  This is a desktop pc.  I did get both monitors to work using nvidia using twinview -- A complicated process!  When checking nvidia now it shows the monitors disabled.  The Nvidia X server setting does show the GPU and all the information.

I was thinking it's seeing the onboard video on the motherboard. Why else would it show laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just enable the screen in nvidia X server settings?

Simply run `nvidia-settings` from the command line and then in the `X Server Display Configuration` panel where you see your screens, select the disabled screen and click on the configuration dropdown to select TwinView.

I attached a screenshot of my configuration (so it doesn't match yours, but at least we'll be sure we're talking about the same thing :) ).
[image: nvidia X settings]

Comment: This is how I got two monitors to work. I used twinview.  It is like one big monitor two screens.  I just went into the nvidia-settings and it shows the displays are disabled. This is what I am looking at now.  Before I even tried "Separate X screen (requires X restart).  That didn't work at all.  If I remember right it went into 2D.  I would like it to work as separate x servers.  I have run separate x servers years ago when I had to edit the xorg.conf file.